# Master Page checked in and approved (as a major version) yet I'm still the only person that can see it

Tags: 2007, master-page, check-out

Topic pretty much says it all. I've checked in a new major version of the master page and approved it, but I'm still the only person who can see this page.

What am I missing here?

This is a SharePoint 2007 environment.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What sort of changes have you made and are related resources like images, CSS etc checked in too?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a cacheing problem.

Are you using output cacheing? Is there a cacheing proxy somewhere? Have other users cleared their browser cache?

Comment: I've cleared the browser cache so it's not that. There is no output caching or caching server either though. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Have you tried iisreset? (drastic, but just to be on the safe side).